# MySQL GROUP BY AVG MAX MIN -> Boolean Error

Tags: mysql

I have modified a number of script code examples, but still end up not being able to resolve an 'Boolean' Error Problem

What I am trying to do is simply get the AVR, MIN and MAX ages for only 7 data areas.

The first code snippet below I got working fine but for just the AVR by area.

The second code snippet is one variation of many for AVR MAX MIN that has me stuck.

---

NOTE: I've eliminated some of the HTML code involved and my actual MySQL connect 'require' line used OK with other code on the page.

*EDIT*:  Sorry, this system will apparently NOT allow some html and php tags inside the code.  I'll see if the lines are still here in the master text entry section to <snip> out - not really needed anyway besides the MySQL I guess.

Thanks!

-stucko

---

This WORKS FINE but for just the AVR by area

```
$sql = "SELECT area, (ROUND(AVG(age))) as avrage FROM mydb GROUP BY area"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while(list($area, $avrage) = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{

*** HAD TO <SNIP> OUT THIS HTML/EMBEDDED PHP CODE FOR DISPLAYING OUTPUT 

}
```

This is my last of many attempts to get THE AVR, MAX & MIN by area

```
$sql = "SELECT 
          (SELECT CONCAT(area, '-', age) from mydb GROUP BY area ORDER BY age DESC limit 1) as MAX, 
          (SELECT CONCAT(area, '-', age) from  mydb GROUP BY area ORDER BY age ASC limit 1) as MIN, 
          (SELECT AVG(age) from mydb) as AVG
           FROM area limit 1"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while(list($area, $MAX, $MIN, $AVG) = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{

*** HAD TO <SNIP> OUT THIS HTML/EMBEDDED PHP CODE FOR DISPLAYING OUTPUT 

}
```

Comment: Please read the help file on the StackOverflow editor. After you paste code, mark it with the mouse and use the `{ }` tool or type Ctl-k. This will mark it as literal code so you can post code with HTML in it.

Comment: You can include HTML/php code. Paste it in, select it all, and then hit the {} button

Comment: Shouldn't `FROM area` be `FROM mydb`?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips! -stucko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm reading that wrong, it's extraordinarily overengineered for what could simply done with:

```
SELECT area, max(age), min(age), avg(age)
FROM mydb
GROUP BY area
```

Comment: Marc B:  OMG- Thank you !!!  I quickly tested it but need to use ROUND on the AVR and reposition the columns/fields.  So sorry I overlooked the special { } code brackets in my initial post.  REALLY APPRECIATED the extremely fast reply.  Amazing!  -stucko